# Nu Wa Ult Max Damage

Tags: smite, moba

Assuming you have unlimited gold to purchase anything, full stacks on items, fire giant buff, damage camp, the 3000 gold elixir to give you increased power(forget the name), AND frenzy relic. What build would give Nu Wa's Ult the most power possible?

Comment: This question is... odd... to answer. You're essentially asking what the most power you can build is... but that doesn't even actually answer the question because magical defense is a thing and you don't know how much your target might have, so you'll need some amount of penetration in order to maximize your damage. So, while I could give you an answer for "how much power can you build and what items are those?" that won't even actually answer the question you are asking.

Comment: I guess it's more like 2 questions. First off, what would be the absolute strongest build assuming they no protection? and secondly, what would be the strongest build if they had as many magical defense items as possible? I'm trying to get a rough idea of how strong she can be. Also, in certain MOTDs it allows for multiples of the same god with reduced cooldown time. I'm thinking that 5 Nu Was with full damage have the potential to clean sweep the enemy team repeatedly

Comment: A fairly definitive question could be asked if a team of 5 Nu Wa's in a high cooldown MOTD are effective. The answer to that is probably not. Nu Wa's ult only adds 30% of your power. In order to be successful, you'll need to engage the team. A more balanced team would probably still win, and any team that brings an Odin has a great chance against 5 Nu Was. Odin's 2, which will have so low of a cooldown to up constantly, will absorb all of the damage from Nu Wa's ult, and then Odin's 2/1 combo, plus his ult, will pretty much annihilate a Nu Was who builds only power and/or penetration.

Comment: I'd expect a team of 5 Odins to win easily, and I would be really impressed if the Nu Was can get more than a few kills in before the Odins take the titan.

Comment: The question came about when a friend got a triple kill with Nu Wa and we started to think that if we all played her and used the ult, if a penta-kill would be possible. All for the jokes really. Thank you for the suggestions though. I might do a breakdown and test a few possible combinations

Comment: @Ellesedil i can attest to the 5 Nu Was not being a guaranteed victory. I was trapped playing against 5 Nu Was in an Assault MOTD, and while they got some multi kills early on in the match, by the end our tanks could endure the Ults, and one of which was Sylvanus, and his healing kept the team pushing. Early game it seems like the deal is sealed, with spontaneous global ult dmg. End game, the 30% power isnt enough, even for full dmg/pen Nu Wa